# How to properly use HERE maps SDK in custom Nativescript plugin?

Tags: android, nativescript, here-api, nativescript-plugin

I included sdk file from https://developer.here.com by this location `my_plugin/src/platforms/android/HERE-sdk.aar`. In java code I can use it like this:

```
package com.here.android.tutorial;
...
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment;
...
private MapFragment mapFragment = null;
private void initialize() {
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
...
```

I tried this:

```
// my-plugin.android.ts
import { Common } from './my-plugin.common';

declare var com: any;

export class MyPlugin extends Common {
    public mapFragment: any;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.mapFragment = new com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment()
    }
}
```

But it shows error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'android' of undefined`

How to properly include `.aar` library file and use MapFragment in Nativescript(JS) code?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Here is solution:

1. To use native lib with Nativescript plugin, it's enough to put lib to `MY_PLUGIN/src/platforms/android` directory. **No need to edit `include.gradle` file!** Nativescript will find library itself. So the directory structure should look like this:

   - MY_PLUGIN/src/platforms

     - ios
     - android

       - AndroidManifest.xml
       - HERE-sdk.aar
2. To make Here SDK works open `AndroidManifest.xml`, add permissions and credentials. So it will look like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
        android:value="{ YOUR_APPID }"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
        android:value="{ YOUR_APPTOKEN }"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, I had to remove/add the platform

```
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
tns run android
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the aar file as dependency into [include.gradle](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Android-Plugins-Infrastructure#includegradle-specification)

```
compile(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')
```

Comment: I tried this, but it shows error: `> Could not find :HERE-sdk:.`

Comment: Are you sure your file name was same?

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle properties to see if you included the Here-sdk like below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['HERE-sdk.aar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

You can also try the following

- Delete the .aar file from project libs file
- Remove Here dependencies lastly rebuild the project
- Paste again the .aar file added the here dependencies
- Clean and rebuild project